# Harmonic Mean on Spark DataFrames in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to compute the **Harmonic Mean** for a DataFrame column with Spark in Scala.

The Harmonic Mean is defined as followed such as for [image] :

[image]

I have used the second equality to define the Harmonic Mean function as followed :

```
// Organize imports 
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column,DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// Define inverse UDF
def inverse = udf[Double,Double](d => (1.toDouble / d))

// Define Harmonic Mean function
def harmonicMean(df : DataFrame, column : Column) : Double = {
    df.count / df.withColumn("inverse",inverse(column)).
              agg(sum("inverse")).first.getAs[Double](0)
}

// Example :
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,4)).toDF
println("H = " + harmonicMean(df,df("_1")))
```

or :

```
df.count / df.rdd.map{ case r : Row => val i = r.getAs[Double]("_1"); (1.0 / i)}.sum
```

But I was wondering if there might be a better approach for doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use UDF or collect data at all. Instead you can solve this using only built-in functions and basic expressions:

```
def harmonic(c: Column) = count(c) / sum(lit(1.0) / c)
df.select(harmonic($"_1").alias("H")).show

// +------------------+
// |                 H|
// +------------------+
// |1.7142857142857142|
// +------------------+
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. But I have totally forgot about built in functions on columns ! Thanks buddy ;)

Comment: My pleasure :) The biggest advantage over UDF is that creates expression which is transparent to Catalyst.

Comment: I even tried to create an UDAF https://gist.github.com/eliasah/9ac79c227fedba89d411 without success. I'm completely lost on the merge and evaluation stage. (This is my first try)

Comment: Here you are https://gist.github.com/zero323/ac6250580435d5670eb6. `merge` is equivalent to `combOp` in `aggregate`.  `evaluate` is like `finish` in custom aggregators.

Comment: Cool thanks for the clarification, the only problem I have is that it's returning `0.0` as an answer and that is what created my confusion in the first place, thus I wasn't sure of what I was doing afterward with it !

Comment: Gist kicked me out. I can't connect to it anymore and my cluster seems to be dead. I'll try to fix it on Monday and I'll keep you posted. Thanks a lot for all the time you spent helping me buddy ! :)

Comment: Ok buddy, thanks ! this is working. I didn't understand what happened. Something very weird with the SparkContext that I can't reproduce anymore. I just restarted it and it worked. I more question, concerning the udf registry, how can I make it global? So I don't need to register it each time I need to use it.